# Programatically make an imageView visible/invisible using a variable

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Kotlin function, that works as expected when an imageView is explicitly called. However when a variable 'cellName' is used the code will not compile.

My objective here is to programatically generate the imageView name and then set/unset its visibility. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

TIA

```
   fun game(view: View) {
        var col = 1
        var row = 0
        var cellName = ""

        object : CountDownTimer(10000, 1000){
            override fun onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Time's Up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                textView9.text = "Time: 0"
            }

            override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                textView9.text = "Time: "+ p0 /1000
                // Hide current position
                cellName = "imageView"+row+col
                imageView01.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
                // Get next random position
                // Show new Position
            }
        }.start()
    }
```

So:
                imageView01.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) --> works
                cellName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)  -- does not compile

Comment: cellName is not a view

Comment: but `cellName` is not a `View`, it is just a `String`

Comment: Thanks for that can you give me some pointers on how I can programatically generate a View name then, that is where I am stuck.

Comment: When you say "programatically generate a View name", you mean for example turning `"imageView" + row + col` into `R.id.imageView01`?

Comment: I think so Ben, yes. I am not sure what R.id. is but the imageView01 is spot on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a view id (aka an `R.id` constant) by using [`Resources.getIdentifier()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

A sample for your code (assuming you're running inside an `Activity`) might be:

```
int row = 0;
int col = 1;
String name = "imageView" + row + col;

int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());

ImageView imageView = findViewById(id);
imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Sorry that this is in Java, not Kotlin. Hopefully you can adapt it.

Comment: If you're not executing this code directly inside an activity, note that `getResources()` and `getPackageName()` are both methods of `Context`, so you can call them on any context object you have access to.

Comment: Ben, the IDE translates Java to Kotlin, so I end up with : val id = resources.getIdentifier(cellName, "id", packageName) which seems OK but then the compiler baulks at : val imageView = findViewById(id) by saying not enough information to infer parameter. Any ideas?

Comment: I have almost zero experience with kotlin, but it is my understanding that you could write `val imageView: ImageView? = findViewById(id)`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to just put all the `ImageViews` in question into a map where the value you have for "cellName" is the key. Then just retrieve each `ImageView` from the map.